# Total rotational energy of oval-shaped object

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation, rotational-kinematics

I am analysing the rotational energy of an oval-shaped ball (after taking a series of videos of a rugby ball bouncing), through the following 3 axes of rotation...:

[image]

...I calculated the angular momentum (L = I*ω) for each axis (x, y and z).
Since angular momentum is a vector, I added them up. However, by doing so, I am no longer capable of calculating rotational energy since the equation for rotational energy is $\ KErot = \frac {L^2}{2I} $ and *I* (moment of inertia) is different for the x-axis compared to the y-axis and z-axis (in other words: as far as I know, there is no overall moment of inertia for an oval-shaped ball, which accounts for all 3 axes of rotation).

Therefore, what I thought of doing in order to calculate total rotational energy is: find the rotational energy of each individual axis of rotation (instead) and then add them up. Would this be correct even though energy is a scalar?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: This works iff you are applying your formula along principal axes of inertia which is the case here for your $x,y,z$ axes according to your drawing. In general, a rigid body has an inertia tensor, written conveniently as a symmetric, positive matrix $J$. In this case, the energy is rather $$K=\frac{1}{2}L^TJ^{-1}L$$ and your formula works in this special case because in your axes are along the eigenvectors of $J$ (principal axes of inertia), which can be seen by symmetry arguments.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Please use MathJaX to enter equations on this site, rather than images.  [You can find a tutorial on how to do so here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  It would be best if you edited this question to conform with these guidelines.

Comment: I think you calculated the angular momentum components of each axes and then add them to a vector

Comment: I appreciate your response @Ipz. However, I am still a high-school student so could you by any chance please simplify your answer because I don't understand it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I’ll try to make my comment more accessible. For a rigid body rotating about a point, you can associate two vector quantities: angular velocity $\vec \Omega$ and angular momentum $\vec L$ (measured in the rigid body’s frame) or $\vec \omega$ and $\vec l$ (measured in reference frame). The issue is that when the object in question is not spherically symmetrical, $\Omega$ and $\vec L$ are not aligned in general, so you cannot define a scalar moment of inertia.

Take for example spherical pendulum with a massless rod attached at one end to the center of rotation and the other end to a point mass $m$ at position $\vec r$ with velocity $\vec v$. In this case, by definition: $\vec l = m \vec r \times \vec v$. On the other hand, you also have by definition: $\vec v=\vec \omega \times \vec r$. You therefore get:
$$
\vec l = m\vec r\times(\vec\omega\times\vec r) \\
= mr^2\vec\omega -m\vec r (\vec r \cdot \vec \omega)
$$
You can check that $\vec l,\vec \omega$ are aligned iff $\vec r,\vec\omega$ are aligned or perpendicular. In the first case, the proportionality factor is $mr^2$ as expected, but in the other case, it is $0$, so there is no consistent way of defining a scalar moment of inertia. In general the relation between the two vectors is more complicated, bit can be expressed mathematically using linear algebra and the relevant mathematical object is called a tensor, which in this cas is called the moment of inertia tensor.

In general, thanks to a mathematical theorem called the spectral theorem, you can always find three orthogonal directions where the vectors are collinear, which are called the principal axes of inertia with the respective proportionality constants the principle ments of inertia.

For the definition of kinetic energy, the relevant quantity is $K = \frac{1}{2} \vec l \cdot \vec \omega$. First off, it is the same in both frames, is conserved in free rotations and has an analogue kinetic energy theorem for rotational motion. You can calculate it simply (again thanks to the spectral theorem) by summing the contributions of each principal axis as if they were independent rotations.

Taking the previous example, you can show that
$$
K =\frac{1}{2} m(\vec \omega \times \vec r)^2 \\
=\frac{1}{2} (mr^2 \omega_{||}+0 \omega_\perp)
$$
with $\omega_{||},\omega_\perp$ respectively the parallel and perpendicular component of $\vec \omega$ with respect to $\vec r$.

Check out the wikipedia article on moment of inertia or Arnold’s Mathematical Methods for Classical Mechanics for more information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Ipz. I still have a doubt though: when you mention that you can calculate rotational energy by "summing the contributions of each principal axis", do you mean: that I must add the relevant vector quantities (ie. either angular velocity or angular momentum)  - which I tried doing in the case of angular momentum but did not work out due to specific values of moments of inertia for each axis; or is it alright if I add the values I obtain for the rotational energy of every independent axis (ie. calculate rotational energy for every axis independently and then add them)?

Comment: Mathematically, I meant:$$K=\frac{\Omega_1L_1}{2}+\frac{\Omega_2L_2}{2}+\frac{\Omega_3L_3}{2}\\ =\frac{L_1^2}{2I_1}+\frac{L_2^2}{2I_3}+\frac{L_3^2}{2I_3}\\=\frac{I_1\Omega_1^2}{2}+\frac{I_2\Omega_2^2}{2}+\frac{I_3\Omega_3^2}{2}$$ with $1,2,3$ labeling the three principal directions of inertia.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help @Ipz! Hope you have a nice day